# Links on the dropdown menu are not working Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I tried to make a mega menu with bootstrap. I use the code of dropdown menu and I make some changes on the code, but the links in the dropdown don't work only if I open the link in new tab. Otherwise, when I press the link it closes the dropdown menu. I think maybe is something wrong with the class or js, but I am not sure.

```css
#logo{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}

  #navbar{
    position: -webkit-sticky;    
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #282b2e!important;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
  margin: 0;
}
  
  #megamenu{
    padding: 30px;
  }
 
  #navlink{
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: #bfbfbf;
font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  #megamenucol{
    align-self: baseline;
  }
  
  
  
  #navlink{
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
  
  #navlink:focus, #navlink:hover {
    color: rgb(211, 152, 48);
}
  
  .hvr-underline-from-center:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 51%;
    right: 51%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #d39830;
    height: 4px;
    -webkit-transition-property: left,right;
    transition-property: left,right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
  

#megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #54595f;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
  
  #h6{
    color: #bfbfbf;
font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  hr {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d39830;
}
  
  #dropdownitem {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    text-align: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
font-size: 14px;
}
  
  #dropdownitem:focus, #dropdownitem:hover {
    color: #d39830;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f8f9fa00;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hover.css/2.3.1/css/hover-min.css" integrity="sha256-c+C87jupO1otD1I5uyxV68WmSLCqtIoNlcHLXtzLCT0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">   
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/"><img src="https://www.dimtiles.gr/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/logo.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav1,#navbarNav2" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarNav1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item ">
                <a id="navlink" class="nav-link  hvr-underline-from-center " href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/">Αρχική</a>
              </li>
              <!----------------- MEGA MENU DAPEDO (START) ----------->
              <div>
                <li class="nav-item " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <a id="navlink" class="nav-link hvr-underline-from-center" href="#">Δάπεδο</a>
                  <div id="megamenu" class="dropdown-menu  w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                        <h6 id="h6">Πλακάκια Δαπέδου</h6>
                        <hr class="solid">
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-33-x-33/">33X33</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%bf%cf%85-30%cf%8760/">30X60</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-45%cf%8745/">45X45</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-50%cf%8750/">50X50</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-60-%cf%87-60/">60X60</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%bf%cf%85-80%cf%8780/">80X80</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-60-%cf%87-120/">60X120</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%bf%cf%85-%ce%bc%ce%b5%ce%b3%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%b5%cf%83-%ce%b4%ce%b9%ce%b1%cf%83%cf%84%ce%b1%cf%83%ce%b5%ce%b9%cf%83/">120X240</a>
                      </div> 
                      <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                        <h6 id="h6">Πλακάκια Τ. Ξύλου</h6>
                        <hr class="solid">
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%cf%84%cf%85%cf%80%ce%bf%cf%85-%ce%be%cf%85%ce%bb%ce%bf%cf%85-15%cf%8760/">15X60</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%84%cf%85%cf%80%ce%bf%cf%85-%ce%be%cf%85%ce%bb%ce%bf%cf%85-15%cf%8790/">15X90</a>
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%bf%cf%85-%cf%84-%ce%be%cf%85%ce%bb%ce%bf%cf%85-20%cf%87120/">20X120</a>
                      </div> 
                      <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                        <h6 id="h6">Παραδοσιακά</h6>
                        <hr class="solid">
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%b1%cf%81%ce%b1%ce%b4%ce%bf%cf%83%ce%b9%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1/">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                      </div>
                      <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                        <h6 id="h6">Επενδύσεις</h6>
                        <hr class="solid">
                        <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b5%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%bd%ce%b4%cf%85%cf%83%ce%b7/">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                        
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </div>
                <!----------------- MEGA MENU MPANIO (START) ----------->
                <div>
                  <li class="nav-item " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <a id="navlink" class="nav-link hvr-underline-from-center" href="#">Μπάνιο</a>
                    <div id="megamenu" class="dropdown-menu  w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row ">
                          
                          <h6 id="h6">Πλακάκια Μπάνιου</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-20%cf%8720/">20X20</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%cf%84%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%87%ce%bf%cf%85-20%cf%8750/">20X50</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%cf%84%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%87%ce%bf%cf%85-20%cf%8760/">20X60</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-25%cf%8750/">25X50</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-25%cf%8775/">25X75</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-30%cf%8760/">30X60</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-30%cf%8790/">30X90</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-33%cf%8755/">33X55</a>
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%bc%cf%80%ce%b1%ce%bd%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%85-40%cf%87120/">40X120</a>
                          
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </div>
              <!----------------- MEGA MENU MPANIO (END) ----------->
                
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarNav2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav  ">
              <!----------------- MEGA MENU KOYZINA (START) ----------->
                <div>
                  <li class="nav-item " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <a id="navlink" class="nav-link hvr-underline-from-center" href="#">Κουζίνα</a>
                    <div id="megamenu" class="dropdown-menu  w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton3">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <h6 id="h6">Πλακάκια Κουζίνας</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%cf%80%ce%bb%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%b1-%ce%ba%ce%bf%cf%85%ce%b6%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%b1%cf%83/">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <h6 id="h6">Ψηφίδες</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B6%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%83/#psi">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </div>
              <!----------------- MEGA MENU KOYZINA (END) ----------->
              <!----------------- EIDIKA (START) ----------->
                <div>
                  <li class="nav-item " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <a id="navlink" class="nav-link hvr-underline-from-center" href="#">Ειδικά</a>
                    <div id="megamenu" class="dropdown-menu  w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton4">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <h6 id="h6">Δάπεδο</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem"class="dropdown-item hvr-underline-from-center" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1-%CF%83%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1/#da">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <h6 id="h6">Μπάνιο</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item hvr-underline-from-center" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1-%CF%83%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1/#to">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <h6 id="h6">Κουζίνα</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B6%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%83/#psi">Ψηφίδες</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <h6 id="h6">Τ. Ξύλου</h6>
                          <hr class="solid">
                          <a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item hvr-underline-from-center" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1-%CF%83%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1/#woo">Όλα τα προϊόντα</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div id="megamenucol" class="dropdown-row ">
                          <br>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </div>
              <!----------------- MEGA MENU EIDIKA (END) ----------->
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a  class="nav-link hvr-underline-from-center" href="#">Επικοινωνία</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: which is not working, I show snipped and all things works perfect

Comment: The links inside the mega menu. For example :<a id="dropdownitem" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.dimtiles.gr/%ce%b4%ce%b1%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-33-x-33/">33X33</a>

Comment: brother dropdown does not work if you specified href attribute with working link without #

Comment: Oh ok, I don't know that, thank you !!!

Comment: I tried a different way with col inside the row and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown only works when `href` have `#` in that